# matplotlib animation with scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot

I have the following code:

```
sim = simulator()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(sim.XY[:,0],sim.XY[:,1])

def animate(i):
    sim.run()
    scat.set_offsets(sim.XY)  # update the data.  
    return scat

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, blit=True, save_count=50)
```

The "sim" object method "sim.run()" updates sim.XY which is (100,2) array.

After my 3rd line I get a scatter plot as expected.

But when I try to animate (from line 5 downwards) I get a error message saying. Can someone help please:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 953, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1732, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1761, in _draw_frame
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())

TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984509/typeerror-pathcollection-object-is-not-iterable-when-adding-second-legend-to

Comment: @Anwarvic that post may not be relevant. I am getting an error when i try to animate. I took care of the multiple return issue issue that post cites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot)

Comment: @AnnZen Not directly. I have found the issue. If I set blit=True the animation does not work and I get the error. Without the parameter the animation works. Can someone explain please what that parameter is doing. .

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068396/matplotlib-funcanimation-error-when-blit-true

Answer (score 0):

What I observed is If I set blit=True the animation does not work and I get the error. Without the parameter the animation works. Can someone explain please what that parameter is doing

Comment: `blit=true` redraws only the plot elements that have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a comma after scat, I believe it should work:

```
def animate(i):
    sim.run()
    scat.set_offsets(sim.XY)  # update the data.  
    return scat,
```

When blit=True, the output is expected to be an iterable:

See here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

> If blit == True, func must return an iterable of all artists that were
> modified or created. This information is used by the blitting
> algorithm to determine which parts of the figure have to be updated.

Putting a comma after scat, makes it an iterable.